# 2 questions on cross-variation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $M$ and $N$ be continuous local martingales and $X=\exp(N_t - \frac{\langle N_t\rangle}{2})$.

1. Why does it hold that:
   $$d\langle M,X \rangle=X d\langle M,N\rangle$$
2. What's the easiest way to see that is $M$ is a local martingale and $V$ a bounded variation process
   $$\langle M,V \rangle=0$$
   I tried the latter using the identity
   $$\langle M,V \rangle=\frac{1}{4}(\langle M+V \rangle-\langle M-V \rangle)$$
   but something doesn't quite add up

Comment: I think you might be missing some continuity assumptions in these questions.

Comment: Well spotted, I edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Hint: By Ito's lemma $dX_t=X_t\,dN_t\,.$
2. $\langle M,V\rangle_t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(V_{t_{i+1}}-V_{t_i})\,.$ Therefore, by the continuity of $M$ and the bounded variation of $V$,

\begin{align}
|\langle M,V\rangle_t|&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n|M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i}|\,|V_{t_{i+1}}-V_{t_i}|\\
&\le\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\max_n|M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i}|}_{0}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n|V_{t_{i+1}}-V_{t_i}|=0\,.
\end{align}