# Covariation of independent semimartingales is zero

Tags: stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation, local-martingales

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent continuous semimartingales on a probability space. I know that we should have $[X, Y] = 0$.

I am able to prove that if $M$ and $N$ are independent continuous local martingales, that $[M, N] = 0$, this is easy by using the sum definition. I want to say "if $M$ and $N$ are the local martingale parts (in the Doob-Meyer decomposition) of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, *they are independent* and hence $[X, Y] = [M, N] = 0$". Is this true, and if so how do I prove it?

Comment: Using the same approach as in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234450/2-questions-on-cross-variation/4234560?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C35.2769#4234560) you should be able to show that the covariations of the bounded variation parts of $X$ and $Y$ with anything else are zero. Then $[X,Y]=[M,N]$ (even without independence).

Comment: @KurtG. That is useful for getting rid of the cross-terms, but how do I conclude that $[M, N] = 0$ if I'm unsure as to whether $M$ and $N$ are independent?

Comment: Without independence you cannot get $[M,N]=0\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. How can I deduce $M$ and $N$ are independent from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are?

Comment: $X$ remains a continuous semimartingale with respect to its natural filtration $\mathcal F^X_t:=\sigma\{X_s: 0\le s\le t\}$. Let $X= M^X + V^X$ be its Doob-Meyer decomposition. Do the same for $Y$, obtaining $Y=M^Y+V^Y$. Clearly $M^X$ and $M^Y$ are independent. You should be able to finish from here, using the fact that $X$ is a semimartingale with respect to $\mathcal F^{X,Y}_t:=\sigma\{X_s,Y_s: 0\le s\le t\}$, *with the same D-M decomposition* (because of independence), and likewise for $Y$.

Comment: That clears it up, thanks! @JohnDawkins